# Basic about Verification

Tags: php, database, security, web-applications, authorization

In the web application, of course in many case we will support CRUD(Create, Retriever, Update, Delete)

Basic programmer will do something like bellow(without Verification ) :

```
delete?room_id=12
update?room_id=13
```

The displayed room_id is only for room that belong to the user/client.
first Authentication is only using user and password. well that's a standard.

But i believe we should not trust the user. The bad user may guess the room_id that's not belong him. like `delete?room_id=199`

I ask my programmer friend, and they even never think about this issue.

So to prevent that, i have a basic solution that to always pass the user_id for any related object. such querying before any action *`is the room_id belong to the user`*.
If this the only solution, so i must to modify all of the query i already write.

The question is, is there any good or better solution for this basic problem ?

Thanks

Comment: @Art : how $_POST can solve this issue ? the basic problem is finding the best way to check is the object belong to the user or not. and that not only one object, but will be may object. like room, address, shirt, etc

Comment: do you have any database which contains both user_id and room_id? , and @Art Planteur , users can post any data too, its just in a hidden field

Comment: My comment was about if a bad user try to modify a GET it can create an error. POST could solve that.

According to your answer above, you need a request to check whether the room_id exist with user_id.
How is your database structure ?

Comment: Upvote for being the only one among you and your colleagues to be concerned about security.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your approach is a good one.  And it really doesn't surprise me that your programmer friends haven't thought about it; unfortunately security seems to be the last thing on most programmers minds.

In a good system, you will perform an *authorization* check on nearly every action performed to see if this particular user is authorized to perform that action.  Its generally good practice to build this check in throughout your app, even for things that you don't normally care if they are authorized for or not: someday you might be.

In your scenario, that action might be to retrieve the room, update the room or even delete the room.

To help things along I have a few recommendations:

1. Make the room_id non guessable if possible.  The easy way, presuming you are already using an int as your primary key, is to encrypt / decrypt it when passing between the client browser and your application.
2. Make sure that on the browser side you aren't passing in the users id but rather pulling that from session or through some other mechanism.  The point is you don't want to trust the user to pass the id to you.
3. Any action that is not a GET, use an HTTP POST to perform.  In other words you shouldn't be putting the ids in the query string at all but rather as post data.

Comment: great, thanks for your recommendation. but i think encrypt and decrypt the id will make the application become slower.

Comment: @ Ahmad, application won't get slower by a few encyptions , using encryption and checking database at the same time is better than just checking the database

Comment: @Ahmad: the amount of processing time spent decrypting / encrypting the id's is trivial to the point that you won't notice it.

Answer (score 2):

assuming you have registered userid in a session when he logs in using: session_register("userid");

then you can do this to check if logged user owns the room (as you have told you have a database which contains roomid and userid at the same time)

```
$connect = mysql_connect("$server", "$dbuser", "$dbpassword")
    OR die(mysql_error());

$room = intval($_GET['room_id']);
$user = mysql_real_escape_string($_SESSION['userid']);

mysql_select_db("$databasename", $connect);
$select = mysql_query("SELECT userid AS uid FROM table WHERE userid='$user' AND room='$room'");
$fetch = mysql_fetch_assoc($select); 
$found = $fetch['uid']; 

if ($found == $_SESSION['userid']){

// User owns this room let him delete

} else {

// FAIL, This user does not own this room

}
```

change the 'table' (which table in database contains both of this info) , 'userid' (user id column name in that table) and 'room' (room id column name in that table)

**EDIT:**
also if your room_ids may have any characters, remove the intval(); from $room and do a real_escaping for it, if room_ids are only numbers don't change it

Comment: Hi, Thanks for you answer and the example. your answer is the same as mine, theoretically and practically. i already mention about that in my first question, is to check any object belong to the current user or not before do any action. came from this, it mean for me to modify all of my query. to adding check before do any action like in this sample, right ?

Comment: you are welcome, yes you need to add your actions where i typed // User owns this room , and add an alert in // FAIL to warn user he doesn't own this room

Comment: As the user ID is already part of the query condition, `$found == $_SESSION['userid']` will always be true if a record was found.

Answer (score 2):

**Don't ever trust** anything your client passes to you. Every request **has to be validated on server** side and checked whether the logged user is allowed to do that action.

Every text input has to be sanitized either on inserting or on viewing. The latter has bigger chance of forgetting and thus providing a field for [XSS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting). I recommend using implicit sanitisation for templates.

Also try to avoid the use of GET method for critic actions. Attacker can always force user to visit the URL (iframe, sending him shortened link). You should also add special generated token to the deletion form to prevent [CSRF attacks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery).